# How can I find out why giving the wrong spec doesn't cause a blowup in my tests?

Tags: testing, clojure, clojure.spec

Parts of my system are specced out really well, but when I change one of the predicates to be something obviously wrong I noticed all my tests still pass and I don't get the usual blowup from spec I've come to rely on.

I can't figure out why this is happening, and I certainly can't reproduce it starting from `lein new test`.

Is there a way I can get `spec.test` to give me a warning when it can't find a spec, for debug purposes, rather than assuming I didn't want to spec out this part of my system?  Can it perhaps help me in some other way with debugging this situation?

Comment: Do you call `spec.test/instrument` before running your tests?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should've stated that explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal reproduction:

```
(ns test.core
  (:require [clojure.spec :as s]))

(defn my-specced-fn [x]
  x)

(s/fdef my-specced-fn
        :args (s/cat :arg int?))

(ns test.core-test
  (:require [clojure
             [test :refer :all]]
            [test.core :as core]
            [clojure.spec.test :as spec-test]))

(spec-test/instrument)

(deftest my-specced-fn-test
  (is (= 1 (core/my-specced-fn 1))))
```

This test passes initially.  I would then go edit `test.core`, change the schema and re-evaluate `test.core`.  After changing the schema with a predicate like `string?` the tests should fail, but it keeps passing.  To solve the problem re-evaluate the test namespace (specifically the call to `instrument`).

Comment: When you say "schema", I assume you mean "spec", specifically the my-specced-fn fdef.

Comment: At the point when you `instrument`, your `my-specced-fn` var is replaced with a new var that is a function that will verify the `:args` of your fdef *as of the time when you instrument*. Changes to that spec will not get picked up until you instrument again.

Comment: Yup, it all makes perfect sense, I just didn't know about the need to re-evaluate the call to `instrument`.  With the reloaded workflow it just worked most of the time :)

Answer (score 2):

spec should error if you try to use a spec that's not defined.

There is no way currently to have it tell you about things that aren't spec'ed. To do so would require instrumenting (replacing) all vars and adding that check.

For your particular problem, if you have a spec that you're changing, I would search for who is using that predicate and then try testing each thing that uses those specs or the original predicate.

One thing that trips people up sometimes is that `stest/instrument` only checks the `:args` specs of functions, not the `:ret` or `:fn` specs (which are only used by `stest/check`).

Comment: You only get errors for top-level specs, not for nested ones.

The problem i'm having is when I change `::foo` as part of a `s/keys` spec.